# Navmesh unity - Click & show/instance Sprite mark

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tengo un navmesh el cual recorro con mi agent con la mecánica clásica de click to move.. pero necesito instanciar un Sprite en el navmesh cuando se hace click antes de pasarle el nuevo Target al agent como en cualquier juego MObA.: pero cuando uso el transform que le paso al agent para moverse el Sprite se posiciona en otro vector3 totalmente distintos.. cuál sería la forma correcta o más eficiente de hacer esto?
Saludos

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir la parte de código donde instancias el sprite y le asignas la posición?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta instanciar un gameobject vacio en la posición del mouse, luego solo tendrás que instanciar el sprite al gameobject vacio.